# Python 3.7 - activate venv error Parameter format not correct 65001 WINDOWS

Tags: windows, python-venv, python-3.7

I just updated my python version to 3.7 but every time i activate my virtualenv i got the following error message: **parameter format not correct - 65001**

Anybody knows what this mean and how to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have had the same Issue. It only happened in Powershell. Windows CMD worked just fine.
And use activate.bat and not activate (without bat).
I hope this helps.

Comment: in case any other straggler finds his way here after trying the cmd as well - check if virtualenv doesn't activate despite this. in my case i got this error, and it took me some time to realize that there was a (venv) in front of the prompt. 
apparently you can sometimes just ignore this error.

Answer (score 12):

I currently had the same issue. 
Please check this page [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/6955d44b41058e3bcc59ff41860bd4cc8948c441) and this [bug report](https://bugs.python.org/issue34144).

> The issue can be solved by modifying the codepage grep of
>   activate.bat: for /f "tokens=2 delims=:." %%a in
>   ('"%SystemRoot%\System32\chcp.com"') do (...

Just add the "." after "delims=:" in your activate.bat file. That worked for me.