# Python modules not executed from the active virtual environment?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I created a virtual environment inside a project folder like this:
`python -m venv venv`
Then I activated it like:

```
.\venv\Scripts\activate
```

Once there the commands are executed as if they were called from base environment. I tried to create an .exe for example, then it was created from base installed modules instead from those in my venv:

```
(venv) C:\Projects\CT_Modules_trunk>pyinstaller --onefile CT_DataAnalyzer.py
```

Could anyone suggest what would be the reason, and how can I work with this created virtual environment?

Comment: Why do you think the modules of the base environment are used?

Comment: It is because of observations. The size of the .exe in the concrete case. Also when I do 'conda list' it shows all packages in the base. When I do 'pip list' it shows those I installed for the venv. Though I am not well versed in this, so I don't get what I might do wrong.

Comment: could you try running `pip freeze` in a terminal/cmd with your venv activated?

Comment: Yeah, pip freeze works as well.

Comment: Does it show different packages than the ones you're expecting?

Comment: It shows the expected packages.

Comment: Also when I activate it, it shows something like: Parameterformat falsch - 65001.

Comment: Does the same happen if you activate using activate.bat instead of activate?

Comment: It is the same outcome.

Comment: Are you using powershell? Maybe try using CMD instead (ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51358202/python-3-7-activate-venv-error-parameter-format-not-correct-65001-windows)

Comment: Actually I found other way to elimintate that error. But somehow the outcome is the same. Thanks for your support!

Comment: What is the other way you have found? Maybe it can help somebody else.

Comment: At delims=: you have to add dot, like:  delims=:. in the activate.bat file

Comment: From anacconda terminal still the same but maybe this is insightful, it shows 
(venv) (base) C:\Projects\CT_Modules_trunk>pip list